# unable to get latest version of jupyterlab in conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, jupyter-lab

When i see the list of packages installed it shows the latest version

```
conda list | grep jupyter
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.6.3            py38h32f6830_2    conda-forge
jupyterlab                2.2.8                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
```

but when i check the version from the command line it doesn't update

```
jupyter lab --version
1.2.6
```

I'm not sure what's going on here? I've tried updating and reinstalling etc.

Comment: Have you find a way ?

Comment: yes, it got fixed, but i don't really know how

Answer (score 0):

While installing it you may be installing it in another environment.
So check the environment variable on which it is being installed.